# Implementing tinymce with angular2

Tags: angular, tinymce

I've been following this video: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=0IXelrVEoWI and the corrosponding github source: https://github.com/tabvn/angular-blog

It works perfectly for creating new content, but I'am facing some problems when trying to load and edit existing content in the same editor.

My html dom element looks like this:

```
 <div class="row">
    <div class="form-group col-lg-10">
      <label for="description">description:</label>
      <text-editor [value]="defaultBodyValue" [elementId]="'description'" (onEditorKeyup)="onBodyTextEditorKeyUp($event)"></text-editor>
    </div>
  </div>
```

In my component, I call this method from ngOnInit():

```
  getDescription(): void {
    let id;
    this.route.params.forEach((params: Params) => {
      id = +params['id'];
    })
    this.descService.getDesc(id).then(desc => this.desc = desc);
    this.defaultBodyValue = "asd";
  }
```

I've hardcoded the description to "asd" for testing purposes.

My editor.component.ts source looks like this:

```
export class EditorComponent implements OnInit, AfterViewInit, OnDestroy, OnChanges {


  @Input() elementId: string;
  @Input() value: any = "";
  @Output() onEditorKeyup: EventEmitter<any> = new EventEmitter<any>();

  baseURL: string = '/';

  constructor() {
  }


  ngOnInit() {
  }


  editor;

  ngAfterViewInit() {
    tinymce.init({
      selector: '#' + this.elementId,
      plugins: ['link', 'paste', 'table', 'lists', 'hr', 'emoticons', 'advlist'],
      skin_url: this.baseURL + 'assets/skins/lightgray',
      setup: editor => {
        this.editor = editor;
        editor.on('keyup', () => {
          const content = editor.getContent();
          this.onEditorKeyup.emit(content);
        });
      },
    });
  }

  ngOnDestroy() {
    tinymce.remove(this.editor);
  }


  didSetValue: boolean = false;


  ngOnChanges(){
    console.log(this.value);
    console.log("TEST: " + this.editor);
    if(!isNullOrUndefined(this.editor) && this.value !== "" && !this.didSetValue){

      console.log(this.value);
      this.didSetValue = true;
      this.editor.setContent(this.value);
    }
  }
}
```

It works perfectly when creating new content, but when I try to edit content, it logs the following to the console:

```
asd
editor.component.ts:55 TEST: undefined
```

UPDATED ngAfterViewInit() function:

```
  ngAfterViewInit() {
    tinymce.init({
      selector: '#' + this.elementId,
      plugins: ['link', 'paste', 'table', 'lists', 'hr', 'emoticons', 'advlist'],
      skin_url: this.baseURL + 'assets/skins/lightgray',
      setup: editor => {
        editor = editor;
        editor.on('keyup', () => {
          const content = editor.getContent();
          this.onEditorKeyup.emit(content);
        });
      },
    });
  }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe that the issue is your use of `this` in your attempt to reference the `editor` variable.  In your setup function you make this assignment:

```
this.editor = editor;
```

...I believe that `this` inside that function would refer to the context of the setup function.  When setup is done running you have not assigned anything to your `editor` variable that is defined in EditorComponent (but outside the setup function).

When you then try to reference the `editor` variable in the `ngOnChanges` method its now referring to the variable in your EditorComponent but since you have never initialized it its value is `undefined`.

EDIT:

If you have the element's ID (as you appear to have in one of your component's variables) you can use `tinymce.get()` and pass it the ID of the original textarea - that should get you the specific TinyMCE instance for that ID.

I believe you can do something like this:

```
tinymce.get(this.elementId)
```

Comment: Hi Michael, i've updated the method in the original question. Unfortunately it dosen't change the outcome. Its still undefined. Was the change what you meant?

Comment: Can you make a sample page at JSFiddle so we can see running code?  Solving scope issues with `this` from partial code is pretty difficult.

Comment: I've tried Michael, but I find it quite complex to replicate... :(  Right now (inspired by what you where saying with the this.editor) I'am trying to use something like:   ngOnChanges(){
    console.log(this.value);
    console.log(tinymce);
    if(!isNullOrUndefined(this.editor) && this.value !== "" && !this.didSetValue){

      console.log(this.value);
      this.didSetValue = true;
      //this.editor.setContent(this.value);
      //tinymce.get(tinymce.editors[1].id).setContent(this.value);
      tinymce.get(tinymce.editors);
    }
    tinymce.setContent = this.value;
  }

Comment: This prints out an object that has to editors in it: editors: Array[1]
0: Editor
length: 1
Description: Editor
__proto__: Array[0]  The last one I think is the one from my html dom element. But I can't seem to set the content for it with: tinymce.get(tinymce.editors[1].id).setContent(this.value);

Comment: This worked out perfectly (with a combination of updating the html element.   ngAfterViewInit() {
    tinymce.init({
      selector: '#' + this.elementId,
      plugins: ['link', 'paste', 'table', 'lists', 'hr', 'emoticons', 'advlist'],
      skin_url: this.baseURL + 'assets/skins/lightgray',
      setup: editor => {
       this.editor = editor;
        editor.on('keyup', () => {
          const content = editor.getContent();
          this.onEditorKeyup.emit(content);
        });
      },
    });
    this.editor.setContent(this.value);

  }

Comment: So I use " this.editor.setContent(this.value);" in the ngAfterViewInit() instead of calling it from the ngOnChanges().